# How to convert a file to bytes and bytes to a file in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4. My requirement is:

I have to convert the file into byte array and save to database varbinary column.

For this I written code like below:

```
public byte[] Doc { get; set; }

Document.Doc = GetFilesBytes(PostedFile);

public static byte[] GetFilesBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();

            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);

            return target.ToArray();
}
```

I am downloading the file by using the following code:

```
public ActionResult Download(int id)
{
            List<Document> Documents = new List<Document>();
            using (SchedulingServiceInstanceManager facade = new SchedulingServiceInstanceManager("SchedulingServiceWsHttpEndPoint"))
            {
                Document Document = new Document();
                Document.DMLType = Constant.DMLTYPE_SELECT;
                Documents = facade.GetDocuments(Document);
            }

            var file = Documents.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DocumentID == id);

            return File(file.Doc.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
}
```

when I am downloading pdf file then it is showing message as "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Any thing else I need to do?

I tried with the following code but no luck

```
return File(file.Doc.ToArray(), "application/pdf", file.Name);
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as in below code in your controller

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\path\to\your\file\here.txt");
byte[] fileBytes= new byte[stream.Length];

stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
//Begins the process of writing the byte array back to a file

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\path\to\your\file\here.txt"))
{
   file.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```

It may helps you...

Comment: same problem is araising. The above code is writing the pdf file but the time I opened the document, it is displaying message as "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.". I need code for .pdf only, not for .txt

Comment: I noticed the problem. The problem is not with the code.The problem is with db column. The column size is varbinary(8000). It is taking max 8kb file, more than 8kb it is skipping all the remaining bytes in db. Suppose file contains 40000 bytes db column is taking 8000 bytes only. So at the time when I am dowloading the file it is showing message as the file is corrupted. For less than 8kb file, everything is woking fine. Even I changed db column to varbinay(max) still it is taking 8000 only. Can you suggest me how to resolve the issue.